# Getting some httpHeader in spring webclient call

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

In my spring boot 2.4.1 application, I'm using WebClient for invoking some external rest services.

In reqular scenario it's pretty straightforward and works fine as I expected:

```
InquiryChequeResponse  response=webClient.post()
    .uri(inquiryChequeUrl)
    .body(Mono.just(requestDto), InquiryChequeReq.class)
    .exchangeToMono(res -> {
            return res.bodyToMono(InquiryChequeResponse.class);
    }).block();
```

But I need to get some values like "`requestTraceId`" from response headers and update the final response.
I tried like this :

```
InquiryChequeResponse  response=webClient.post()
    .uri(inquiryChequeUrl)
    .body(Mono.just(requestDto), InquiryChequeReq.class)
    .exchangeToMono(res -> {
            String requestTraceId= res.headers().asHttpHeaders().getFirst("requestTraceId");
            Mono<InquiryChequeResponse> inquiryCheque= res.bodyToMono(InquiryChequeResponse.class);
            inquiryCheque.block().setRequestTraceId(requestTraceId);
            return inquiryCheque;
    }).block();
```

But I get following exception :

```
block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, whichis not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-2
```

My question is what's wrong and how can I get some specific request header and include it in my final response?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I managed to work out which technologies you use and help you regardless, but you'll get more eyes on your issue if you do next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to wait on the *Mono* and then working with the contents you should use the methods on *Mono* and supply functions (or lambdas) that manipulate it's contents.

In your case you want to use *map*.

```
    .exchangeToMono(res -> {
            String requestTraceId = res.headers().asHttpHeaders().getFirst("requestTraceId");
            return res
                .bodyToMono(InquiryChequeResponse.class)
                .map(ic -> {
                    ic.setRequestTraceId(requestTraceId);
                    return ic;
                });
    })
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried but res does not recognize map

Comment: I suppose that should be `res.bodyToMono(InquiryChequeResponse.class).map(...`

Comment: Sorry, I left out the call to `bodyToMono`. Updated

Comment: Thanks, @Raniz, It did work, Do you think is it the right way or there are better options as well?